# Highlight specific text in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a text something like:

```
LOREM IPSUM 

DOLOR SIT amet, 

1. consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo LIGULA EGET dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus

  SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS 

 PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA

 LUCTUS PULVINAR, HENDRERIT ID

2. parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam  

  SUMMERY: FELIS, ULTRICIES NEC. 

3. Pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede  

  SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS 

 PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA

vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede

MOLLIS PRETIUM.
```

Now i want to color that specific capitalized text started with SUMMERY, that mean i have to color

*SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS 
 PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA
 LUCTUS PULVINAR, HENDRERIT ID*

*SUMMERY: FELIS, ULTRICIES NEC.*

*SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS 
 PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA*

How can i do that? Or how can i get those value in array of string? array should looks like:

```
["SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS 

 PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA

 LUCTUS PULVINAR, HENDRERIT ID", "SUMMERY: FELIS, ULTRICIES NEC.", "SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS 

 PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA"]
```

Comment: is it randomize color? or given color?

Comment: not a random color. It will be given color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the way to do that with Regular expression. Here is the code for do that.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'highLightText'
})
export class HighLightText implements PipeTransform {
  transform(summary: string): any {
    
    let cleanedString = summary.replace(/\\.br\\\d{3} /g, '\\.br\\');
       const regexReported = /(?<=SUMMARY:)(.+?)(?=\\.br\\\\.br\\\s+Reported and)/gm;
  
    var segment = regexReported.exec(cleanedString); 
    if (segment == null || segment.length === 0)
    {
      const regexDoctor = /(?<=SUMMARY:)(.+?)(?=\\.br\\\\.br\\\s+Dr)/gm;
      segment = regexDoctor.exec(cleanedString);
    }
    if (segment == null || segment.length === 0)
      return summary;
    else {
      if (segment[0].indexOf('SUMMARY:') > 0) {
        
        var value = this.replaceBreaks(summary);
        if (value.includes('SUMMARY:<br/> <br/>')) {
          value = value.replace(new RegExp("SUMMARY:<br/>", "g"), "SUMMARY:")
          let highLight = value.replace(new RegExp("SUMMARY:", 'g'), '<span class="sixteen"> SUMMARY:');
          let removingSpan = highLight.replace(new RegExp('.\s+<br/>\s+<br/> <br/>', 'g'), '.</span><br/> <br/>');
          return `${removingSpan}`;

        }
        if (value.includes('SUMMARY: <br/><br/><br/>')) {
          value = value.replace(new RegExp("SUMMARY:<br/><br/>", "g"), "SUMMARY:");

        }

        let highLight = value.replace(new RegExp("SUMMARY:", 'g'), '<span class="sixteen"> SUMMARY:');
        let removingSpan = highLight.replace(new RegExp('<br/> <br/>', 'g'), '</span><br/> <br/>');
        return `${removingSpan}`

      }
       else {
          return cleanedString.replace('SUMMARY:', '').replace(segment[0], '<span class="sixteen"> SUMMARY:' + segment[0] + "</span>");
      }
      }
       
  }

  public replaceBreaks(value: string) {
    let newValue = value
      .replace(/\\.br\\\d{3}/g, "<br/>")
      .replace(/\\.br\\/g, "<br/>");
     
    return `${newValue}`;
  }
    }
```

```css
.sixteen{
color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understandings are correct then you need to modify certain changes to your code. Here is the code if you looking for:

> AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  data = [
    {
      "text": "1. consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo LIGULA EGET dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus",
      "child": [
        {
          "text": "SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA LUCTUS PULVINAR, HENDRERIT ID",
          "color": "red"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "2. parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam",
      "child": [
        {
          "text": "SUMMERY: FELIS, ULTRICIES NEC.",
          "color": "green"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "3. Pellentesque eu, pretium quis,sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede",
      "child": [
        {
          "text": "SUMMERY: ET MAGNIS DIS PHASELLUS VIVERRA NULLA",
          "color": "blue"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede MOLLIS PRETIUM.",
      "child": []
    }

  ]
  constructor() { }
}
```

> App HTML code

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div>
    LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT amet,
    <div *ngFor="let pText of data; let i=index">
        <p>{{pText.text}}</p>
        <div *ngFor="let cText of pText.child;">
            <p [ngStyle]="{color: cText?.color}" style="padding-left: 20px">{{cText.text}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Here is an [ONLINE Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ur9r7i)

Please let me know if I am unable to get your situation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but i cannot change those text into JSON. I am getting HL7 parsed value which looks like "\.br\301 \.br\301           DEMODATA DEMO\.br\301 \.br\301           ITEM NUMBER: A00/ 00000\.br\301 \.br\301". i changed those values in HTML format which will looks like <br><br>DEMODATA DEMO<br><br>". And i have to show those data same as HL7 file so with JSON i cannot keep same design. I have managed to color for single line but with multiple lines it is not working properly.

Comment: Can you edit some code in the online demo and I will check it, then I can help you.